# Outlook 2013 crashing with Microsoft ActiveSync Account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 with my MSN email address as ActiveSync. It was working fine two days ago but all of a sudden it starts crashing down after few seconds and also it shows status as disconnected.

So far I have created a new outlook and windows profile but that didn't work. If anyone else has the same issue please guide me through.

Answer (score 1):

You can check logs using event viewer to find out what caused the crash. Run eventviewer on your computer and go to Application then look for an error caused by Outlook.

Also, check if you have applied all security updates or updates for your office products using windows updates.

Try to run outlook on safemode using this command "outlook.exe /safemode", if this works, the cause of outlook crash is likely due to the add-in installed on your outlook. Removed or disabled add-ins from outlook.

You might also want to try uninstall it from your PC and reinstall it.